# Store files in external path to application folder using getExternalFilesDir(String), MediaStore, or Intent#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am developing an application, a function that I need is that I can open the camera to take a photo and store it in the path **Pictures/Example** I save the image in that path so that it can be opened from the google photos application.

With this fragment I create the path and name of the image and open the camera:

```
private void openCameraTocaptureImage() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                    "com.example.cameraimage.fileprovider",
                    photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}
```

My doubt is present when invoking `createImageFile()`

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES+"/Example");//********* Here is my doubt ******
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

So far the application meets what I need, takes a picture and stores it in **Pictures/Example** and can be viewed from the Photos application, but reading the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment) I found this:

**getExternalStorageDirectory**

> This method was deprecated in API level 29.
>   To improve user privacy, direct access to shared/external storage devices is deprecated. When an app targets Build.VERSION_CODES.Q, the path returned from this method is no longer directly accessible to apps. Apps can continue to access content stored on shared/external storage by migrating to alternatives such as Context#getExternalFilesDir(String), MediaStore, or Intent#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT.

I decided to use `getExternalFilesDir`, So I tried to replace

`File storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES+"/Example");`

with

`File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES+"/Example");`

So the code looks like this:

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES+"/Example");
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

But this causes my photo to be stored in **Android/data/com.example.cameraimage/files/Pictures/Example** it is not the path I want and it is not shown in Photos App

The main question is, should I stop using `getExternalStorageDirectory()` even though it works?
If I have to change how can I use any of the alternatives so that I can store photos in **Pictures/Example** and display the images in the Photos application?

Comment: "I cannot store photos outside my application folder" does not match "in my Android emulators 10 and Android R is fully functional to me getExternalStorageDirectory ()". You might want to edit your question and provide a [mcve] of what you are trying and what exactly your results are.

Comment: @CommonsWare An apology maybe I could not explain, I already edited the question, sorry for the bad English

Comment: "One question is why if getExternalStorageDirectory is deprecated it still works for me on android 10 and android R?" -- you probably have `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` on the `<application>` element in your manifest. That should stop working on Android 10 once your `targetSdkVersion` reaches 29, and should need to do that later this year to be able to ship your app on the Play Store (and some other distribution channels).

Comment: Thanks, I am new to this but I am already understanding some things, one last question, you know how to store the photos outside the folder of the app itself with Context#getExternalFilesDir(String), MediaStore, or Intent#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT?

Comment: For `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, you should be able to pass the `Uri` that you get into `EXTRA_OUTPUT`. For `MediaStore`, in theory you should be able to `insert()` an entry and pass the `Uri` that you receive via `EXTRA_OUTPUT`. `getExternalFilesDir()` specifically does not write outside the app's unique external storage location.

Comment: OK thank you very much